# Change Shape of JSON Serialized Object Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, datatables

I'm trying to change the structure of my serialized JSON in Django. Currently it looks like this:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "dates": [
        {
            "date": "2021-02-03",
            "entry_id": 1,
            "indicator": "D"
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-02-04",
            "entry_id": 1,
            "indicator": "D"
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-02-05",
            "entry_id": 1,
            "indicator": "2"
        }
    ],
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "dates": [
        {
            "date": "2021-02-09",
            "entry_id": 2,
            "indicator": "K"
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-10",
            "entry_id": 2,
            "indicator": "K"
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-11",
            "entry_id": 2,
            "indicator": "K"
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-01-18",
            "entry_id": 2,
            "indicator": "K"
        }
    ]
}
```

However I am aiming for a response that is structured like this:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "dates": {
        "20210203": "D",
        "20210204": "D",
        "20210205": "2"
    }
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "dates": {
        "20210209": "K",
        "20210110": "K",
        "20210111": "K",
        "20210118": "K"
        }
}
```

Currently my simplified models+serializers like this:

```py
class Dates(models.Model):
    date: date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Datum')
    indicator: str = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True, default=None, blank=True, verbose_name='Indikator')
    entry: Entry = models.ForeignKey(Entry, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='bookings')

class Entry(models.Model):
    pass


class EntrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dates = DateSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ('id', 'dates',)
        read_only_fields = ('id',)

class DatesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    entry_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Dates.objects.all(), source='entry.id')

    class Meta:
        #depth = 1
        model = Dates
        fields = (
            'date', 'entry_id', 'indicator'
        )
        read_only_fields = ('date', 'entry_id')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        booking = Dates.objects.create(entry=validated_data['entry']['id'],
                                         indicator=validated_data['indicator'],
                                         data=validated_data['date'])

        return booking
```

I have tried adding a `to_representation` function to the Dates serializer, however I'm still getting a `list` of `dicts` instead of a "flat" dict.

```py
    def to_representation(self, data):
        return {data.date.strftime('%Y%m%d'): data.indicator}
```

It probably has something to do with the `many=True` flag, however I'm not sure how to remove it without losing also the functionality to automatically serialize json back to the objects. The flat structure is required, in order to make DRF work with the `Datatables Editor`, as every date needs a certain column in the table, identified by a unique name, in my case `dates.YYYYmmdd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the dates serializer a method field and implement the serialization yourself:

```
class EntrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dates = SerializerMethodField()  # implicitly `get_dates`

    def get_dates(self, instance):
         return {
             date.strftime('%Y%m%d'): indicator
             for (date, indicator)
             in instance.dates.all().values_list("date", "indicator")
         }
```

Comment: This works perfectly – I'm very impressed. Can this also deserialize the JSON back to the objects, as to update or create date models for a given entry?

Comment: SerializerMethodFields are always read-only, so in that case you'd need a custom `update()` method on the serializer (and maybe this would be refactored into `to_representation()` and `dates` would be marked a `DictField` or similar).

Comment: So if I understand if correctly there are two ways of handling it – a custom `update()` method on the view or another `serializer` `dates` uses? I cannot simple have a `get_dates` and `update_dates` on the already existing serializer

Comment: There are many ways to handle it... :-) The update (or create) method would be on the Entry serializer; since there's a collection of Dates instead of a single one, you can't put the method on DateSerializer. The update/create method would consume the dict from the input `data` and create or update Date objects attached to the (possibly newly created) Entry object.

Comment: Quick follow up question – is it also possible to pass a value of the original `Entry` `queryset` to `SerializerMethodField`? Reason being I am querying `Entry` with a certain time period (`start: date` and `end: date`) and have to add empty "padding" dates, if an `Entry` does not have a corresponding `Dates object` in the time period. edit: Or is there a better way to solve this entirely?

Comment: You can use the serializer context for that, it's passed down through the serializer hierarchy (`self.context` in a serializer) from your view set.

Comment: Creating a custom `update` or `create` method does not work btw, because that code is never reached. The API returns "the field `dates` is read only."

Comment: Yes, you will need to change the field to a DictField as I mentioned in an earlier comment :)

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work, as the `RelatedManager` is None, unless I add `many=True` which `DictField` doesn't allow. Any other idea? I also messaged you on CodeMentor.